# How to redirect displayed data on screen to a file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using ngrok for creating links for our internal server. There are two cases how the ngrok displays the data.

First Case: It displays the status of the server being hosted then if it is successful it will just stay on the command line without exiting.

Second Case: It displays the status of the server being hosted then in it fails it will exit the program and display errors in command line.

What I tried is redirect the displayed status on the command line to my output file named `output_data` but what it only collects are the errors on the second case.

I tried using these commands:

```
echo $(./ngrok start -all) >> output_data
```

and

```
./ngrok start -all > output_data 2>&1
```

but all they do is just send the output to `output_data`

Comment: The second example should work for your case, as it sends all `stdout` and `stderr` to the file? What else do you expect?

Comment: the displayed data at second case is not being sent to `output_data`, it only receives the output of the application

Comment: What do you mean by `displayed data`? Can you show it with an example?

Comment: what i mean about the `displayed data` are the server status, connection tries, links provided, etc. with colored texts. They only appear at the first execution of the program, if the connection fails, ngrok clears the data on the command line and they are replaced with errors with only white texts

Comment: it depends on how the program, ngrok, is written it can check whether standard output is a terminal and doing something different depending the case ;  for example command ls --color=auto will not output special sequences if output is not a terminal

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul, so what can you suggest for me so that I can get the first data it displays?